# Can I remove an embedded document in Mongoid without persisting?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

Definitely related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23128008/clearing-embedded-mongoid-documents-without-persisting), but since there was no clear answer, I feel like I should ask again. Is there *any* way to remove an embedded document from a Mongoid embeds_many relationship, without persisting?

I want to modify the array of embedded documents in-memory - and then persist all changes with a single UPDATE operation. Specifically, I'd like to:

1. Modify arrays of embedded documents (add embedded doc / remove embedded doc / edit embedded doc / etc).
2. Possibly make other changes to the TLD.
3. Persist all changes with a single database call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to remove an embedded document using Mongoid without saving. The trick is to make your changes from the parent object using `assign_attributes`. For exmaple:

```
class MyParent
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String
  embeds_many :my_children

  def remove_my_child(child)
    assign_attributes(my_children: my_children.select { |c| c != child })
  end
end

class MyChild
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :my_parent

  def remove
    parent.remove_my_child(self)
  end
end

my_parent = MyParent.first
my_first_child = my_parent.my_children.first

# no mongo queries are executed
my_first_child.remove

# now we can make another change with no query executed
my_parent.name = 'foo'

# and finally we can save the whole thing in one query which is the
# reason we used an embedded document in the first place, right?
my_parent.save!
```

Comment: People seem to forget that `embeds_many :things` isn't magic, it is pretty much just "add an array of hashes field called `things` and wrap those hashes in `Thing` instances".

Answer (score 0):

After two more years of using Mongoid, I've learned there's no operator for what I was trying to achieve. Removing an embedded document with Mongoid always results in a database call.

In situations like this one, it's easier to bypass Mongoid and use the `mongo-ruby-driver` directly.

Comment: I believe I found a way to do this so I added an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try mongoid's

```
update_all()
```

[Documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/moped/Moped%2FQuery%3Aupdate_all)

Ex: If I wanted to make all my users Joe

```
User.update_all(name: 'Joe')
```

will behave exactly as you would expect.

Comment: Can you explain how this is not related?  Unless I'm horribly mistaken, update_all WILL allow you to persist changes to any set of embedded documents with a single operation.

Comment: I asked about removing an embedded document "without persisting". `update_all` will save changes to the database.

Comment: `update_all` also modifies multiple documents. My question refers to a single top-level document (TLD).

Comment: Ah, my confusion, the way the question is worded led me to believe that you meant multiple child documents.  You want to make changes to a child document AND some other change to the parent document in a single db operation?

Comment: Could you also clarify what you mean by "remove an embedded document without persisting"?  That seems contradictory.

Comment: If `Parent` class `embeds_many :children`, then `Parent.first.children` is an array. I'd like to add/edit/remove elements from the `children` array without saving anything to the DB. I'd also like to be able to say `parent.some_field = "new_val"`. Then I'd like to call `parent.save` and have all my changes persisted in a single UPDATE op.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I believe your own answer is correct.